# Ubuntu Power Ccomplex Management

Tags: power-management

```
Hardware:

dell xps 15 9570

90 watt power brick

60 watt TB3 dock
```

I want to use my powerbrick on the go or when I need to do hardcore processing and my 60 watt TB3 dock for my desk. How can I restrict my power-usage to the max power draw? I could definitely add a **static configuration** to **powertop**, but at that point it would not be adjustable.. **ideas?**

Comment: You can limit processor package power a lot by limiting the maximum CPU frequency. How, depends on your processor and which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using, but I suspect this will work: `echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. To monitor processor package power use turbostat (linux-tools-common package), suggest this command: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. On my main test server mains power ~= 30.1 watts + processor package power.

Comment: Woah that’s awesome and simple. 

That said - the other part of my issue would be to determine the max power draw over TB3. The dock is rated for 180 watts overall and 60 watts for charging.